# Ubuntu Software & LibreOffice 7.5 Won't Start

Tags: software-center, libreoffice

Prior to shutting down computer (Ubuntu 22.04) everything worked fine. When I came back a few days later neither LibreOffice 7.5 nor Ubuntu Software would start up.Totally mystified. Any suggestions?

The following has been added after @waltinator suggested running journalctl  --since="-5 minutes". it's a portion of the output, including both before and after attempting to start "Ubuntu Software"...

```
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** systemd[2844]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1811.
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** systemd[2844]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** systemd[2844]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[296916]: Failed to do gtk init. Waiting for a new session with desktop capabilities.
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[296916]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33...
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[296916]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
Jul 19 12:20:35 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[296916]: Loop exited. Forcing reload.
Jul 19 12:20:37 tim-*** systemd[2844]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jul 19 12:20:37 tim-*** systemd[2844]: Started snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software.feff5749-f19c-4c6e-987d-f9ac7307a9b2.scope.
Jul 19 12:20:37 tim-*** audit[296920]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list" pid=296920 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jul 19 12:20:37 tim-*** kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1689787237.299:670): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list" pid=296920 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jul 19 12:20:37 tim-*** snap-store[296920]: cannot open display: :0
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** systemd[2844]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1812.
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** systemd[2844]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** systemd[2844]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[297103]: Failed to do gtk init. Waiting for a new session with desktop capabilities.
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[297103]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33...
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[297103]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
Jul 19 12:20:38 tim-*** snapd-desktop-i[297103]: Loop exited. Forcing reload.
```

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl  -b 0` to watch your system start up and discover the hardware. Use `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` to see what got logged in the last 5 minutes. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: run `libreoffice` in the terminal and post the output

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi
I did that but it opened a different version of LibreOffice (7.3...) that I have installed. I can open that one with the Gnome GUI. I don't know what the command is for the v. 7.5 installation.

Comment: @waltinator
I ran journalctl -b 0 and saw the most recent bootup info but no idea how to interpret.
Also, I ran the --since command and got some interesting output, of which I copied a portion into my original post. I thought there was a better way to post terminal output but can't remember.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files

Comment: Read `man logger`. A syslog format log entry has 4 fields: Date/Time, hostname, process\[PID\]: freeform message. It tells you when, what host, who, and what they said. The first 3 fields are generated by the logging system, the freeform message is generated by the program.

Comment: Try completely removing snapd (`sudo apt purge --autoremove snapd`), and reinstall snapd. Then install snap-store and libreoffice from within snapd.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - I'll try that next week after I return home. Thanks!

Comment: New problem...  
Suddenly, my Ubuntu system password is not working! I tried to remove an installed app and it would not accept my password. Also I went to Settings and tried to change my password, which I could not do. If I shut down, I'll probably not be able to start it up again. Looks like I'm going to have to remove and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.